# Tracing components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react project, and I am new with react and the project, and the project is quite big. So I have run the project locally and need to trace a rendered component to the js file that render it. Any help about how doing that would be appreciated. I am using vscode as code editor and chromedev tools for inspecting and debugging.

Comment: [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) could be helpful.  I don't know if it specifies files, but it does show the component hierarchy which you could then trace in the code manually.  Combine that with other efforts like searching the codebase for some likely-unique string that's in the component you're looking at (text copy, class name, etc.).

Comment: I know my question is kind of bad and sorry for that, but I have been trying to do so about three days now with no good results. I don’t know if I should understand how react works or it just the codebase so big

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Note: [also available for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/react-devtools/) (for those who hate Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of dev tools that can you help you when writing React.

For your specific request, I recommend using [chrome react developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) which will show you the component names of the DOM elements when you inspect them.

That should help you search for that specific component in your editor.